# Returning a promise using promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

I have 2 functions that resolve a promise and another 3rd constant that is simply an integer. Here I tried `Promise.all` in order to return promise resolved.

```js
const a = Promise.resolve('First returned');
const b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {resolve('second returned');}, 300);
});
const c = 123;

Promise.all([a,b,c]).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

My question is, since the 3rd constant is simply an integer and doesn't resolve a promise, how it is included in the result. The result I get is  `["First returned", "second returned", 123]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any item in the iterable object which is passed into the Promise is not an instance of the Promise, it will be ignored and passed to the `then` results using `Promise.resolve` method. Concise, it will be resolved automatically.

From the [**Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> If the iterable contains non-promise values, they will be ignored, but
>   still counted in the returned promise array value (if the promise is
>   fulfilled):

Comment: In case of every `iterable` object

Comment: also promises helps in executing async code. Here if i setTimeout then it will wait until it has been resolved, only then it will go to next promise. So is that syncronous?

Comment: Because you have used `resolve` in the `setTimeout` callback, so it will wait until resolved will be called and then pass to the `then`. But it doesn't mean that it is synchronous. Synchronous means that the rest call after the Promise `then` will stop until `then` works

Answer (score 0):

in Promose.all(...), if the iterables are non-promised values, there results will be either

- Resolved by Default  OR
- Result will deduced based promised value

These 3 examples will make it clear

```
// resolved by default

let a = 100;
let b = 200;

Promise.all([a,b]).then(function(){
    console.log("Promised Resolved");
});
```

Inferred from the results - Resolved

```
// Resolved here
Promise.all([a,b, Promise.resolve("R-Text")]).then(function{
   console.log("R-Test Promise Resolved...");
}).catch(function(text){
   console.log("R-Test Promise Rejected...", text);
});
```

and Inferred from the results - Rejected

```
  // Rejected here
    Promise.all([a,b, Promise.resolve("R-Text"), Promise.reject("Rejected")]).then(function{
       console.log("R-Test Promise Resolved...");
    }).catch(function(text){
       console.log("R-Test Promise Rejected...", text);
});
```